# Let $f$ be holomorphic on an environment of $D_{R}(a)$. Prove $|f(a)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{|f(a+Re^{it})|dt}$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I don't know how to proceed with this one:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on an environment of $D_{R}(a)$. Prove $|f(a)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{|f(a+Re^{it})|dt}$

Could anyone give me a hint? It has another part, but I need to solve this first to solve the second statement.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: $D_R(a)$ usually means an open disc.

Comment: It's exactly as it's on my notes

Comment: We don't have your notes. We have what we see in your question. So tell us what $D_R(a)$ is.

Comment: It's an open disk centered at $a$ with radius $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that$$f(a)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,\mathrm dz,$$with $\gamma(t)=a+Re^{it}$ ($t\in[0,2\pi]$).